# Facebook on Jabber

Tags: chat, facebook, jabber, xmpp

I am using a XMPP client to connect to facebook (Apple Messages), and I find that not all messages make it to my client. Many get lost on the way.

Am I the only one with this experience? Is there a way to improve? Who's to blame?

Comment: When this happens, are you using the client exclusively, or are you replying in the Facebook web interface?

Comment: sometimes it could be that facebook is open yes, or the facebook mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a problem with XMPP in general. See e.g. [here](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/14680) or [here](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/14720). There are suggestions that this might occur because you've set to disallow all apps in your facebook privacy settings.

Comment: Rather a problem with Facebooks XMPP implementation.